# Values coming back as 'undefined' in for loop inside ES6 promise

Tags: javascript, socket.io, es6-promise

So I'm currently writing an inventory application, and I'm running into some issues inserting values into my database.  What happens is that I get a list of item objects that contain information about that specific item.  I then push those items into a list and call a socket which runs a for loop to insert those items into my database, but when I look at the table where these items should be, all of their values are set as `undefined`.

My item object looks something like this:

```
let ItemObject = {
 ID: id,
 Name: name,
 Qty: qty
}
```

The promise that calls the DB sequence:

```
export const insertItem = async (list) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {

            console.log(list);

            for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                const writeSolutionData = `INSERT INTO database (ID, Name, Qty) VALUES ("${list.ID}", "${list.Name}", "${list.Qty});`;

                const response = await db(writeSolutionData, "Inserting Item");

                resolve(response);   
            }

        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR database.insertItem: " + e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
};
```

This is the socket that gets called:

```
socket.on('insertItem', async (data, callback) => {        
        try {

            const results = await insertItem(data);
            callback(true);

        }
        catch (error) {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
```

When I console log the list before the for loop, I get what I would expect the output to be, but after this promise finishes the data that's returned in my DB is `undefined`.  I also receive no errors from the callback either.  The idea of ES6 promises are still new to me, so forgive me if what I have here is not correct.  This is the first time I've tried implementing a for loop within an asynchronous promise like this, so it was no surprise to me that this didn't work the first time around.

If anyone has any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: If the selected answer has solved your problem, that's great, but that answer doesn't address the misuse of promises. You are resolving the promise inside a loop, so if you try to evaluate your promise later you will only be able to see the first value you resolved. This may not be an issue for you now but later down the road if you need access to all the values. Consider this simple jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f4hLju6k/, which uses your method first and then uses Promise.all to return all values. Open the console and run the fiddle to see the output. I would look into promises more.

Comment: @wizloc Promises are still a gray area for me that's for sure, so I will definitely look more into them.  All my values are inserted into my DB, so if I need to access them I can just call a query to get them.  So I'm confused as to why I would need to access these values from the promise if all I'm doing is putting them into my DB anyway.

Comment: @wizloc Great suggestion. I've added it to my answer. Now the promise will resolve after all of the `db()` promises have resolved, instead of only the first one. @Michael, if that is the case, then why would you resolve a value at all, as you do in your initial question?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier being honest here, I originally had a for loop that called the socket and would resolve on just one item, so i figured it would be the same within a for loop if it was in the promise.  I understand now that this is not the correct way to do it.  Thank you for your updated answer.  This will help me better understand how these things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insertItem` does not have to be an `async` function. Just return the `Promise` and use `async` it the promise callback, only in that scope the `await` keyword is needed.

An `async` function automatically returns a `Promise`, but you need a `Promise` constructor to use the `resolve` and `reject` methods. It is basically the same thing but with different syntax and options.

Also I've noticed that your loop has an error. You try to select `list.ID`, `list.Name` and `list.Qty` from the array, but instead should get the values from the items **in** the array.

I also found a missing `"` at the end of your query string.

```
export const insertItem = (list) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    list.forEach(item => {
      const writeSolutionData = `INSERT INTO database (ID, Name, Qty) VALUES ("${item.ID}", "${item.Name}", "${item.Qty}");`;
      const response = await db(writeSolutionData, "Inserting Item");
      resolve(response);   
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("ERROR database.insertItem: " + e);
    reject(e);
  }
});
```

### Addendum

Updated the answer with usage of `Promise.all`. Suggested by @wizloc.

This will loop all of your items and return promises from the `db()` function and stores them into a new array. `Promise.all` will then resolve whenever all of the promises in the array have fullfilled and return the values of each promise in a single array.

```
export const insertItem = (list) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    const responses = list.map(item => {
      const writeSolutionData = `INSERT INTO database (ID, Name, Qty) VALUES ("${item.ID}", "${item.Name}", "${item.Qty}");`;
      return db(writeSolutionData, "Inserting Item");
    });
    const results = await Promise.all(responses);
    resolve(results);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("ERROR database.insertItem: " + e);
    reject(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: omg I can't believe I missed that.  I should've been doing ```list[i].ID```...  I will still give this a try, but that might honestly be the problem that's causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with what

```
const writeSolutionData = `INSERT INTO database (ID, Name, Qty) VALUES ("${list.ID}", "${list.Name}", "${list.Qty}");`;

const response = await db(writeSolutionData, "Inserting Item");
```

actually does (aside from the obvious), but since `db(writeSolutionData, "Inserting Item")` is awaitable, it returns a promise. As I mentioned in comments, your original code is resolving in the first iteration of the loop, therefore if you need to access the values returned from your promises down the road, you will find you only have access to the first value. You asked why you would need the values since you can just query for them afterwards, I can't answer this since I don't know anything about your project, what you plan to do with the data after it is inserted, etc. But another benefit of promises is error handling by chaining `.then()` and `.catch()`.

You could simplify your entire insertData method to the following

```
socket.on('insertItem', async (data, callback) => {
    const promises = data.map(x =>
        db(`INSERT INTO database (ID, Name, Qty) VALUES ("${x.ID}", "${x.Name}", "${x.Qty});`)
    )

    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(values => {
            // Do something with values array
            callback(true)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Error handling
            callback(false)
        })
});
```

Doing it this way will ensure `callback(true)` is only called if all items were inserted successfully, and will error (`callback(false)`) if any of the items failed.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, these all have really good points to them and I will use this to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

I think `insertItem` is not an async function because it doesn't contain `await`...

```js
export const insertItem = /*async <- remove it */ (list) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {

            console.log(list);

            for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                const writeSolutionData = `INSERT INTO database (ID, Name, Qty) VALUES ("${list.ID}", "${list.Name}", "${list.Qty});`;

                const response = await db(writeSolutionData, "Inserting Item");

                resolve(response);   
            }

        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR database.insertItem: " + e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: the await is in there. look at line ```const response = await db(writeSolutionData, "Inserting Item");```

Comment: @Michael no, it is in a Promise, not in function. If you want to do so use `return await new Promise...`

Comment: this might better assist me if you could provide an example. Thank you.

Comment: @Micheal Pls refresh the page

Comment: I will give this a try and see what happens.

Comment: After doing this, I get the same issue.